# is there a way to prevent install

Tags: system-installation

I want my kids to use a USB stick to run ubuntu.  I am afraid they will accidentally choose the option to install ubuntu instead of try ubuntu.
Is there a USB version without the install option ?

Comment: Just install Ubuntu to USB stick. I've done that. But it's not the best system setup - horribly slow even in command line

Comment: Why don't you set virtual machine? That is absolutely safe, much faster, much more comfortable.

Comment: yes a virtual machine ... virtualbox is free .. it will run much better than off a USB and you wont have to worry about it messing up your existing OS .. you can set snapshots on that too so even if that gets screwed up you can just use one of the snapshots

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Install Ubuntu on the USB stick.  It'll then run no different (except for speed) than running off your hard drive.  The performance should be better than what you are getting when trying to run under the `Try Ubuntu` option.

You can also consider installing Ubuntu on the computer as a multiple boot configuration so that by default the computer boots into their OS and specify your OS when you are ready to boot to your environment.

Comment: To clarify, this would require booting Ubuntu off of one USB stick, and then choosing to install to a second, separate USB stick, correct?

(Of course, booting from DVD and installing to USB would be another option)

Comment: @that's correct.  When running the install you have a choice of all the attached `drives` both USB (external) and internal for your install destination.  You can choose the partition as well as where to place the boot (the grub installation).